# Parsing and formatting xml data before loading it into jQueryUI tabs (via AJAX)

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to load content into jQueryUI tabs via AJAX using the technique described in the documentation here:  http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#ajax.

```
$('#tabs').tabs();

<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
     <li><a href='/link/to/xml/'>Tab1</li>
     <li><a href='/link/to/more/xml/'>Tab2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Since my data source is XML, I need to parse and format it before displaying it in the relevant tab.  How do I get access to the data after it's been retrieved, but before it's displayed in the tab?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this method http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#event-load you can then manipulate the data beforeLoad or after load depending on the event type that you want to handle.

Comment: The load event works, but only if I'm retrieving text type data.  If I'm retrieving xml data (which I am), I get a javascript error:  HierarchyRequestError: Node cannot be inserted at the specified point in the hierarchy.  Any ideas about why and how to avoid?